Contour plot with only one contour label per line for unstructured or ungridded (non-rectangular) data
In cntrlabel contour plot
there is an excellent approach to the same problem when the 3D datafile corresponds to a rectangular grid.
Now, when the values are ungridded (that is, randomly scattered), gnuplot needs to grid them by interpolation, via the set dgrid3d nx,ny command where nx and ny are the number of points along the x and y axes respectively.
I've done that then I've applied the solution proposed at  cntrlabel contour plot
The best I've obtained, after having tried a number of variants, is this: if several lines happen to correspond to the same contour value, only one line is labeled (with -fortunately!- only one cntrlabel). The others are not labeled.
My (reduced) datafile "datos.txt" (previously sorted with zsort) is as follows:
 0   66  0.2
 0   69  0.3
 0   70  0.3
 0   72  0.7
 0   74  0.1
 0   74.1    0.1
 0   79  0.3
 0   80  0.2
 0   81  0.3
 0.1     61  -0.1
 0.1     70  0.3
 0.1     74  0.7
 0.1     75  0.8
 0.1     75.1    0.3
 0.1     78  0.2
 0.2     73  0.4
 0.2     75  0.5
 0.3     59  0.5
 0.3     74  0.4
 0.3     75  0.1
 0.3     76  0.6
 0.3     78  0.2
 0.4     71  0.3
 0.4     73  0.4
 0.4     74  0.6
 0.5     54  1.1
 0.5     69  0.2
 0.5     76  0.6
 0.5     84  0.3
 0.6     55  0.3
 0.6     67  0.3
 0.6     68  0.4
 0.6     76  0.4
 0.6     77  0.5
 0.6     79  0.2
 0.6     80  0.4
 0.7     68  0.2
 0.7     72  0.1
 0.7     73  0
 0.7     76  0.4
 0.7     76.1    0.4
 0.7     77  0.5
 0.7     77.1    0.3
 0.7     81  0.2
 0.8     46  1
 0.8     54  0.1
 0.8     63  0.5
 0.8     68  0.3
 0.8     73  -0.1
 0.8     74  0.3
 0.8     78  0.3
 0.8     81  0.3
 0.8     82  0.2
 0.9     50  0.8
 0.9     56  0.5
 0.9     60  1.2
 0.9     65  0.3
 0.9     70  0.7
 0.9     74  0.2
 0.9     79  0
 0.9     80  0.2
 0.9     80.1    0.1
 1   69  0.4
 1   76  0.5
 1   81  0.2
 1.1     54  0.3
 1.1     73  0.1
 1.1     76  0.3
 1.1     76.1    0.4
 1.1     81  0.2
 1.2     56  0
 1.2     75  0.3
 1.2     79  0.1
 1.3     68  0.3
 1.3     75  0.3
 1.3     82  0.3
 1.4     46  0.2
 1.4     66  0.7
 1.4     71  0.2
 1.4     78  0
 1.4     81  0.3
 1.4     81.1    0.4
 1.5     45  0.9
 1.5     60  1.3
 1.5     71  0.1
 1.5     76  0.1
 1.5     82  0.2
 1.5     82.1    0.2
 1.5     82.2    0.2
 1.5     84  0.2
 1.6     55  0.9
 1.6     57  1.4
 1.6     71  0
 1.6     81  0.1
 1.6     82  0.1
 1.6     83  0.1
 1.6     84  0.3
 1.7     62  0.3
 1.7     66  1
 1.7     75  0.4
 1.7     76  0.3
 1.7     78  0.3
 1.7     78.1    0.1
 1.7     80  0.1
 1.7     84  0.3
 1.8     56  0.3
 1.8     63  0.3
 1.8     67  0.6
 1.8     69  0.3
 1.8     77  0.1
 1.8     77.1    0.4
 1.8     78  0.3
 1.8     79  0.3
 1.8     84  0.2
 1.9     49  0.2
 1.9     53  0.3
 1.9     53.1    0.3
 1.9     54  0.2
 1.9     79  0.1
 1.9     82  0.3
 1.9     84  0.3
 2   60  1
 2   68  0.2
 2   73  0.5
 2   77  0.2
 2.1     45  1
 2.1     61  0.6
 2.1     66  0.4
 2.1     82  0.1
 2.2     61  0.1
 2.2     64  0.2
 2.3     64  0.5
 2.3     70  0.2
 2.3     76  0.1
 2.4     73  0.1
 2.5     53  0.2
 2.5     68  -0.1
 2.5     74  0.1
 2.5     79  0.1
 2.6     43  0.9
 2.6     65  0.8
 2.6     70  0.1
 2.8     61  0.4
 2.9     61  0.5
 3   54  0.4
 3.1     69  0.2
 3.2     57  0.3
 3.2     67  0.4
 3.5     65  1.1
 3.8     54  0.3
 3.8     60  0.2
 3.9     53  0.6
 3.9     65  0
 4.1     46  0.9
 4.1     48  0.8
 4.2     56  0.8
 4.3     43  1.1
 4.3     45  1.1
 4.6     44  1
 4.7     44  0.7
 4.7     46  0.9
 4.7     52  0.7
 5.5     44  0.9
 6.6     70  -0.5

And my code is
reset session
set dgrid3d 900,900 qnorm 9 # I use large parameters because data are highly oscillatory
set table $Contour1
    splot "datos.txt" u 1:2:3
unset table
set contour
set view 0,0,1
set cntrparam levels incremental -0.5,0.1,1.5 
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
        set cbrange[-0.5:1.5]
        set colorbox vertical user origin 0.93,0.38 size .02,.585

set xrange [0:*]
unset surface
set table $ContourLabels
     splot "datos.txt" u 1:2:3
#    splot $Contour1 u 1:2:3   # THIS VARIANT YIELDS A CONTOUR PLOT WITH NUMERICAL ARTIFACTS (SEE THE 2ND PLOT BELOW)
unset table

set cntrlabel format "{/:Bold %.1f}" font "Times-New Roman, 12" # THIS HAS NO EFFECT (?)
plot $Contour1 u 1:2:3 w image notitle, \
     $ContourLabels      u 1:2 w l notitle lc "black", \
     $ContourLabels      u 1:2:3 every ::1:1:1:1 w labels notitle 


The plot is as follows (except for labels and minor details):

And using the variant (see the script), it looks like this:

I guess the reason why it displays one cntrlabel for only one line among all lines with same cntrvalue, is that the every command (see at the end of the script) deals only with blocks but not with sub-blocks. And I have many sub-blocks per block (as many as contours for the same value)
So does anyone know of any workaround to produce one cntrlabel for each contour ? Even better: one cntrlabel for every other contour ? (this, I guess with every)

I suggest that the resulting plot would be easier to interpret if you assigned a distinct color and/or dash pattern for each contour level that you want labelled, and then provide a key that shows which pattern indicates which level.
Alternatively, in version 6 you could plot it with contourfill and provide a distinct color for each level. In this case the contour levels will match the colors perfectly. If you want fewer colors than contour lines (or vice versa), that is quite possible by adjusting the contour increment of the lines separately from that of the color fill boundaries.
set dgrid3d 900,900 qnorm 9

set view map
unset key

set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set cbrange[-0.5:1.5]
set colorbox vertical user origin graph 1.05, 0 size graph 0.02, 1

set xrange noextend
set yrange noextend

# These control the fill
set cbtics  -0.5,0.1,1.5 font ",8"
set contourfill cbtics

# These control the lines
set contour
set cntrparam levels incremental -0.5,0.1,1.5 
set cntrlabel onecolor

# Use a coarser grid when generating labels
function $smallgrid() << EOF
    set dgrid3d 45,45 qnorm 9
EOF

splot 'contour.dat' with contourfill, \
      '' with lines lc "black" nosurface, \
      g=$smallgrid() '' with labels pointnumber 1

See also https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_6.0/contourfill.html
Revised answer
To the best of my knowledge there is currently no way to tell gnuplot "place only one label for this contour level even though it is represented by multiple line segments in the plot".  The closest I can think of is to use a coarser grid so that contours are not broken up into so many pieces.  Setting the limit to one label per line segment is then closer to the desired limit.
The functionblock syntax in gnuplot 6 can be used to change the gridding from inside a plot command.  The revised plot below adds contour labels on a 45 x 45 grid with one label per line segment. The trick is to use a dummy definition g = $smallgrid() to force a single execution of a function that resets the grid parameters.


.@Ethan I appreciate your input, certainly useful. My main purpose however was to place only one cntrlabel on top of each contour (for the sake of simplicity, let's forget to place only one contour on alternate contours for the time being. Hopefully that, I will be able to make it myself). As I said, the difficult point here is that for each contour value there are several lines, not just one (that is, there are several data sub-blocks inside each data block). Besides, to make cntrlabels well visible, I tried set cntrlabel format "{/:Bold %.1f}" font "Times-New Roman, 12" but didn't work

@ifffam See revised answer

This already is a fantastic workaround. Should there be some very short contour lines, would there be an easy way (I mean not another whole script) to enforce gnuplot not to place any cntrlabel on those very short contour lines ? (something like "if number of points of this contour line is less than  n  then don't place any cntrlabel on it)

No, but that's a good idea.

@ifffam this reminds me to this post. The contour lines are often segmented into several pieces. Well, you could join them together, but (for some reason which I don't know) they are in reverse order which would require some extra effort, but it can be done. If the data shows so many little islands with high contour line density as in your case I'm not sure if there will be an automated procedure which will always give good looking results. So, manual adjustment might be necessary.

@theozh indeed that post is the one I referred to above :) though that case was a much simpler one... a regular grid, an analytical function to plot and (mainly) one single contour line for each contour value. If you have an idea of how to modify the last 3 lines of your 2nd script for the present case (which are just the last 3 lines of my script), I would greatly appreciate it, just for learning since the solution proposed by @ Ethan is already great

@ifffam oops, sorry, I overlooked the links in your question. I will think about it, but I guess in terms of simplicity and result, Ethan's solution is probably close to the best you can get.

@theozh in fact it's just the last line, not the last three lines of your 2nd script, that doesn't work for the present case: every ::1:1:1:1 labels only one line per contour value, and pointnumber 1 cannot be used with plot, but with splot

@Ethan sorry if this is a silly question... rather than having splot... with contourfill, I would like to have just with pm3d or with image, but none of them are accepted... what should I do to just have smoothly degrading color ?

Your original post showed the pm3d output.   My preference would be for discrete color levels in this case, but if you prefer smooth color you can go with what you already have.  Maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "degraded" color.

Maybe better than "smoothly degrading color" I should say "smoothly changing color". If I go with what I already have, I should plot $Contour1 u 1:2:3 w image along with the other splots of your script. But gnuplot (to my knowledge) cannot plot and splot at the same time (unless with a workaround). So in order to use your script, I should write splot... with pm3d, but with pm3d is only allowed with plot, not  splot.

No, you have that wrong.  pm3d is 3D only. Contouring is also 3D only.   So pm3d+contour commands both use splot.   Your original script used splot to generate both a surface and contours, but it saved the output to tables rather than displaying the plot directly.  Then you used plot to treat the saved tables as 2D data and approximate the surface as pixels from an image.  But that two-step process is not necessary. You can just use splot to create the output graph; no need to reprocess it via tables into a 2D form.

[continued].   To see the continuous pm3d coloring rather than the discrete contour level colors,  revise the script I showed in two ways. (1) Add a command set pm3d explicit. (2) Change the line splot 'contour.dat' with contourfill to splot 'contour.dat' with pm3d.

Not only it has worked perfectly, but even better than expected: the smallest contours don't display any label (which would be a bit overwhelming since there are many in my plot). I guess that has something to do with the x & y grid point numbers of set dgrid3d
